# How to connect to web service from meteor or nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I'm designing a package (either nodejs or meteor) that connects to a web service, this web service is going to provide "live" data so I need some sort of listener or trigger event that tells me when there is new data or when some data have changed etc. is this possible or I'm just dreaming?

any hint would be very appreciated

thanks in advance

Comment: http://socket.io/ and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern for starters

Comment: Are you going to build the webservice as well? Or it already exist.

Comment: we are going to build the web service (but other developer that's no me, he is using Java) we are in a research stage right now, so any input is welcome :-)

Comment: Can you explain what kind of "live" data is it? Also what kind of clients are the publisher and subscribers? Are they all servers, browsers...?

Comment: we haven't decided yet, most likely the live data is going to be a bunch of JSON objects, the subscriber would be nodejs using socket.io (for now. thanks to @ceejayoz)  and the publisher would be java. both servers

Answer (score 0):

You should consider a message queue like RabbitMQ (http://www.rabbitmq.com/). Then, the service your colleague is writing could send messages to a queue, and your Node.js process is listening for incoming messages.

See

- http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-java.html
- https://github.com/postwait/node-amqp